# Magento 2 How can i create model factory for custom module?

Tags: magento-2.1, custom, model, dependency-injection, factory

Hi i am trying to collect some data from the database but the create method of the injected factory fails and no errors are showed. 
Here are my classes.

magento\app\code\Cosmo\Basemodule\Model\DatiInterface.php

```
<?php
namespace Cosmo\Basemodule\Model;
interface DatiInterface
{

}
```

magento\app\code\Cosmo\Basemodule\Model\Dati.php

```
namespace Cosmo\Basemodule\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface;
class Dati extends AbstractModel implements DatiInterface, IdentityInterface
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Cosmo\Basemodule\Model\ResourceModel\Dati');
    }

    public function getIdentities()
    {
       //todo
    }
}
```

magento\app\code\Cosmo\Basemodule\Model\ResourceModel\Dati.php

```
<?php
namespace Cosmo\Basemodule\Model\ResourceModel;
use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb;

class News extends AbstractDb
{
    /**
     * Define main table
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('exampletable', 'entity_id');
    }
}
```

magento\app\code\Cosmo\Basemodule\Model\ResourceModel\Dati\Collection.php

```
<?php
namespace Cosmo\Basemodule\Model\ResourceModel\Dati;
use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;

class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{
    /**
     * Define model & resource model
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(
            'Cosmo\Basemodule\Model\Dati',
            'Cosmo\Basemodule\Model\ResourceModel\Dati'
        );
    }
}
```

And then block where i inject the factory
magento\app\code\Cosmo\Basemodule\Block\Main.php

```
 <?php
 namespace Cosmo\Basemodule\Block;

 use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
 use Cosmo\Basemodule\Model\DatiFactory;

 class Main extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
 {
    protected $_datiFactory;

    public  function __construct(Context $context, DatiFactory $datiFactory)
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_datiFactory = $datiFactory;
    }

    public function _prepareLayout()
    {
        echo 'pippo<br \>';
        $dati = $this->_datiFactory->create();
        var_dump($dati->getCollection());
        exit();
    }
}
```

I tried in many ways but create() fails and then nothing is executed.

Comment: Wait I sent you GitHub link for CRUD Module. Where you easily  learn how to use Model, ResourceModel , Collection in magento2.

Comment: Why not inject the collection factory instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem that I see with your code is that in your call to parent::__construct, you are missing the `$data = []` argument. Try changing your code to this:

```
class Main extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_datiFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        DatiFactory $datiFactory,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_datiFactory = $datiFactory;
    }
}
```

After you have made that change, clear your `var/generation` and `var/di` directories.

Even though `$data` is an optional argument, it still need to be included in your arguments for your constructor for proper creation of the interceptor class.

Additionally, have you created the class `Cosmo\Basemodule\Model\ResourceModel\Dati`? I don't see it in the various blocks of code that you posted. If you forgot to create that class, that will also be a problem.